# How to use history model of the vue-router correctly?

Tags: vue.js

When I use the history model of `vue-router` and press `F5` to refresh browser I get a **404 Not Found error**.

The api document says that I have to do this in the service to resolve this problem, but I don't understand and I want to get more information on how I should do it.

And I use springboot as service framework, as the api document says, my service have no page returned to match /* request.

How can I use the history model of vue-router correctly?

Anyone,any idea,thanks

Comment: Could you please show us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: Everything is well documented, you need to configure your web server to redirect the pages to `index.html`. There are several examples in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: Is the documentation updated after I read it?
No any example in the documentation in my memory and just some word.
Or am I too careless to see?
Thank you again anyway!